# change style of elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 4 pictures with greyscale style added, on desktop on hover greyscale is remove so you can see de colours but thats not intuitive on mobile so I just want to remove greyscale style when user scroll down for each of them, pictures are like 3, 2, 1, GO, so I want to give that sense of 
Countdown while user scrolling. How can I do that?

Thanks!

I have this, but is not working:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#div1').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#div2').height();
    var cc = $('#div3').height();
    var dd = $('#div4').height();
    var ff = $('#div5').height();
    if(scroll > os + ht){
        $('#div1').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > ht + cc){
        $('#div2').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > cc + dd){
        $('#div3').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > dd + ff){
        $('#div4').addClass('blue');
    }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

.div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.div.blue {
  background-color: #15158F;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="div">
image 1
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
image 2
</div>

<div id="div3" class="div">
image 3
</div>
<div id="div4" class="div">
image 4
</div>
<div id="div5" class="div">
Div 5
</div>
```

I added this code to function and css to styles and I add the ID on html, but I dont know why is not working:

```js
add_filter('avf_social_icons_options','avia_add_custom_social_icon', 10, 1);
function add_custom_code(){
?>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#go1').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#go2').offset().top;
    var cc = $('#go3').offset().top;
    var dd = $('#go4').offset().top;
    if(scroll > os){
        $('#go1').addClass('color');
    }
    if(scroll > ht){
        $('#go2').addClass('color');
    }
    if(scroll > cc){
        $('#go3').addClass('color');
    }
    if(scroll > dd){
        $('#go4').addClass('color');
    }
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_code');
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:479px){.go.color{filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'//www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0,0 1 0 0 0,0 0 1 0 0,0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");-webkit-filter:grayscale(0%)}}
```

I got this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Can you include your code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the offset top of all your elements and compare it to window scrollTop and your done.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#div1').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#div2').offset().top;
    var cc = $('#div3').offset().top;
    var dd = $('#div4').offset().top;
    var ff = $('#div5').offset().top;
    if(scroll > os){
        $('#div1').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > ht){
        $('#div2').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > cc){
        $('#div3').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > dd){
        $('#div4').addClass('blue');
    }
    if(scroll > ff){
        $('#div5').addClass('blue');
    }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

.div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.div.blue {
  background-color: #15158F;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" class="div">
image 1
</div>

<div id="div2" class="div">
image 2
</div>

<div id="div3" class="div">
image 3
</div>
<div id="div4" class="div">
image 4
</div>
<div id="div5" class="div">
Div 5
</div>
```

Comment: When I add this(<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
) to function.php all my site crash and all the effects dont show, do you know why is happening?

Comment: I think that's because <script> is an HTML tag and is not defined in PHP. I only add this to the snippet so I can run my jquery code. if you have included jquery in your website, remove this script, but remember to include jquery before the codes you have written with jquery.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how can I archive this (include jquery before the codes you have written with jquery)

Comment: you can, for example, add jquery in the <head> of your page or before starting any of your <script> tags that use jquery. you can include it using <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js></script> . If you are using Wordpress, it adds jquery to the head of HTML page by default. I wish it helps you. sorry if I explain bad.

Comment: I understand thanks, and I insert the code to function on my wp but is not working, it works if I add <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js></script> but then may theme elements go away, sorry but I dont know what to do in order to have it working

Comment: well, I think I found the problem. The jquery code gives color class to the elements. the problem is that you are i.e give class color to #go2 by comparing the scroll to the offset-top of the #go1. correct your conditions and it will work fine. i.e for #go2 your condition must be (scroll > ht) not (scroll > os)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use offset top for all images and just a simple class change in media query only for mobile devices, so that scroll effect will show only on mobile not on desktop**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#div1').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#div2').offset().top;
    var cc = $('#div3').offset().top;
    var dd = $('#div4').offset().top;
    var ff = $('#div5').offset().top;
    if(scroll > os){
        $('#div1').addClass('colorize');
    }
    if(scroll > ht){
        $('#div2').addClass('colorize');
    }
    if(scroll > cc){
        $('#div3').addClass('colorize');
    }
    if(scroll > dd){
        $('#div4').addClass('colorize');
    }
  if(scroll > ff){
        $('#div5').addClass('colorize');
    }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

.div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 600px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.div img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
.div:hover img {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  div.colorize img {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1" class="div">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/500?1" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="div">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/500?2" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="div3" class="div">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/500?3" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="div">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/500?4" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="div5" class="div">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/500?5" alt="" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: System dont let me give you the correct answer too, sorry, but I really apreciate both!